# SQL date selecting

Tags: sql, mysql, date

I want to be able to select all database rows where the month and year are the same as what I am searching for.  Since the DATE field has year, month, and day, how do I search with year and month?

Comment: I hate to say it, but I agree.  He beat me by at least 5 seconds. ;)

Comment: I think it was 42...not that I was counting :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE ( YEAR(myfield) = '2009')
  AND ( MONTH(myfield) = '1')
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblTableName 
WHERE Month(ColumnDate) = Month(MyDate) 
    AND Year(ColumnDate) = Year(MyDate)
```

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient is to create the start and end date of the range that you want, so that you compare the dates as a single value instead of extracting the year and month properties from each date.

Example:

```
select SomeField
from SomeTable
where SomeDate >= ? and SomeDate < ?
```

(Note that the first comparison is inclusive and the seond is exclusive.)

Create the start and end date to use as parameters: (example in C#)

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1)
DateTIme end = start.AddMonths(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

In **MySQL**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  date >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM @mydate), '01'), '%Y%m%d')
   AND date < STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM @mydate), '01'), '%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

This will efficiently use an index on the `date` field.

Comment: +1 on being so..., well..., complete. This is the n'th post I see you making about SQL, it seems you eat SQL for breakfast.

Comment: Thanks :) I've really been writing SQL for a living for almost 10 years already :)

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on what database backend you are using. IN SQl Server I would use

```
where year(datefield) = @year and month (datefield) - @month
```

to do this.

or you could build a where clause by creating a date range

where datefield between 20090101 and 20090201

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [YEAR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) in mysql.